# Jmeter PostProcessor with Groovy and fetching content of response data

Tags: groovy, jmeter

In JSR223 PostProcessor I am using this method to get the response data:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
```

Here is a snippet of my json output is like this

```
XmlItemResult:[[xPath:/Blocks/Block[001], name:abc, folder:\A\abc\a1, id:84, information:[[xPath:/Blocks/Block[001], result:Block number 1: abc], [xPath:/Blocks/Block[001]/Steps/CallSteps/Step[001], result:Call step StepNo 1],
```

folder:\Voice133, id:2542, information:[[xPath:/TestCases/TestCase[001],

This response, as you see contains two things which I am interested in:

```
folder:\A\abc\a1, id:84,
folder:\Voice133, id:2542,
```

I need to get the id value for only this line --> folder:\Voice133, id:2542,
note 2542 is variable and can be different each time and after each run.

I tried

```
json.find ("Voice133, id:(.+?),")
```

Comment: Could you please share your json file in its simplest form? I will get back to you with a snippet to get the result. Note: JSON slurper parses text or reader content into a data structure of lists and maps. So you can accesss them just as you do with a map or list. In your case it will be a map.

Comment: To use json slurper, the string has to be a valid json. You might wanna use regex extractor if your response has a specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not a valid JSON, you can check it yourself using any [online JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/), therefore you won't be able to use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html), you will have to go for Regular Expressions instead.

In Groovy you can use `=~` - [Find Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_find_operator) in order to be able to extract the required value(s), example code would be something like:

```
def response = 'XmlItemResult:[[xPath:/Blocks/Block[001], name:abc, folder:\\A\\abc\\a1, id:84,' +
        ' information:[[xPath:/Blocks/Block[001], result:Block number 1: abc],' +
        ' [xPath:/Blocks/Block[001]/Steps/CallSteps/Step[001], result:Call step StepNo 1], '

def matcher = (response =~ 'folder:\\\\A\\\\abc\\\\a1, id:(\\d+),')

if (matcher.find()) {
    log.info('Folder ID = ' + matcher.group(1))
}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Regular Expression]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)